# How to find a Bean instance of MongoRepository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to use a MongoRepository, but Spring complains, that no instance of the MonoRepository-Interface is in the context.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Document(collection = "tableItems")
class TableItem {

    @Id
    public String id;
    public int roundNbr;
}

interface TableItemsRepository extends MongoRepository<TableItem, String> {
}

@Service
class TableItemsService {

    @Autowired
    public TableItemsService(TableItemsRepository tableItemsRepository) {
    }
}
```

The server complains:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in backend.TableItemsService required a bean of type 'backend.TableItemsRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'backend.TableItemsRepository' in your configuration.
```

my maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I get a bean instance of my MongoRepository?

Comment: Remove the `spring-data-mongodb` dependency, add `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and make sure you have properly configured MongoDB.

Comment: The `spring-boot-starter-mongodb` makes your dependency management easier and includes the proper version for this Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependency is incorrect.

`spring-data-mongodb` only makes it compile:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But you need additional dependencies, to make it run. For convenience you can import `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`, which will import all required artifacts as transitive dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That is simply not true, the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` just makes dependency management easier and makes sure you have the correct version (that has been tested with that version of Spring boot) and might include a missing dependency. It is not a requirement to use the starter.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for pointing this out - my "sloppy" formulation was not 100% correct. Of course it is not `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` itself, that solves the issue, but its transitive dependencies. I reformulated the answer.